# How can I get good Y axis intervals when plotting in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot a vector (with dynamically changing size / values) that will have roughly 50-150 elements, with values ranging from something like `0.3331` to `1.7378` (random example).

Is there a way to plot this so that 
a) the values on the y axis are only presented to 2 decimal places. 
b) y axis starts from minimum value rounded DOWN to the closest 0.5, c) y axis ends at maximum value rounded UP to the closest 0.5 and d) there are 10 intervals.

So from the example of `0.3331` as minimum and `1.7378` as maximum, y axis would start at `0` and finish at `2`.

This is my attempt at setting the intervals:

```
yMin = floor(minValue)
yMax = ceil(maxValue)
yInt = yMin:(yMax-yMin)/10:yMax
```

I'm quite the newbie with programming in general and this doesn't work like I want it to. I have tried a lot of things and just can't seem to get it right. Is anyone able to provide me with a solution for this? I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. For the limits I already posted a solution. What do you mean by plotting only 2 decimal places? Did you just try `plot(myvec)`? Is is not enough to just perform this here? `plot(round(myvec*100)/100)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can round *up to* or *down to* a certain value by using this code

```
minvallimit = floor(minval/roudingvalue)*roundingvalue
maxvallimit = ceil(maxval/roudingvalue)*roundingvalue
```

so e.g.

```
0 = floor(0.3331/0.5)*0.5
2 = ceil(1.7378/0.5)*0.5
```

Next topic: rounding up to *2 decimal places*

```
roundedvalue = round(myval*100)/100
```

Comment: You mean: `maxvallimit = ceil(maxval/roudingvalue)*roundingvalue`